# Google Places API Alternative

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

My IOS app (Swift 5) HEAVILY relies on googles places API specifically the Places Autocomplete. I'm using it to get addresses and places to show on the map for users. Is there an alternative for this now that they have stopped supporting it or is there a way to fetch autocompleted places using a string. ANY help is greatly appreciated. It's essential for my app to continue working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has not stopped supporting Places Autocomplete. You can migrate to the new Places SDK for IOS following [this migration guide](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/client-migration). You may also refer to the places autocomplete guide [here](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/autocomplete).

Hope this helps!