# Operation failed due to exceeding the per-device usage rate limit Places API

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, google-maps, google-places-api

We are using Google Places SDK for autocomplete to get address, but experiencing a strange error suddenly.

```
Operation failed due to exceeding the per-device usage rate limit. This status code shouldn't be returned during normal usage of the API. It relates to usage of the API that far exceeds normal request levels.
```

As per research I found that need to update pods. We updated pod 'GooglePlaces', enabled both Maps SDK and Places API, but still getting the same error. Any other solution which fixes the issue?

Comment: do you have increase your quota limits?

Comment: @HardikS There is no option to increase it in my projects google console. Where it has to be done?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are getting [this error](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/reference/group___places_errors.html#gga5c09127e1f646ddab0484209c90539f3a5ac9dbb5c87650b47602c6e47aaa4279):

> *kGMSPlacesDeviceRateLimitExceeded* - Operation failed due to exceeding
>   the per-device usage rate limit.
>
> This status code shouldn't be returned during normal usage of the API.
>   It relates to usage of the API that far exceeds normal request levels. See the [usage limits guide](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/usage-and-billing#usage-ilmits) for more information.

The aforementioned guide states:

> Rate limit is 100 requests per second (QPS). It is calculated as the
>   sum of client-side and server-side requests for all applications using
>   the credentials of the same project.

Make sure you are not exceeding this QPS limit. And double check that you've migrated from the deprecated Places SDK. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59803091/11742502

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by updating 'GoogleMaps' and `'GooglePlaces'` pod. Then all my error was gone. What wasted so much of my time was google didnot exactly report the error that has to be fixed. Instead it showed a different and false error.